# Bootstrap progress label not displayed entirely

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a progress bar with a custom label inside:

```
<div id="progress" class="progress mb-1" style="height: 20px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 5.0%" aria-valuenow="5.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">1/20</div>
</div>
```

It works like a charm. However, the label is not displayed entirely on the left for small screens:

[image]

I've tried to get around this in a couple of ways  (hardcoding the width of the bar to 2 for 1, playing around with colours) but I wonder if this is a more elegant solution for this?

Comment: Please post your code in a working snippet

Comment: Appears to be doing what you told it to `style="width: 5.0%"` correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second div containing the label, something like this :

```
<div id="progress" class="progress mb-1">
    <div class="progress-label">1/20</div>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 5.0%" aria-valuenow="5.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">1/20</div>
</div>
```

With some style :

```
.progress {
  position: relative;
}
.progress-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
.progress-label {
  color: #0275D8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Preview :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue with the following code:

```
<div id="progress" class="progress mb-1" style="height: 20px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 5.0%; min-width:100px;" aria-valuenow="5.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">1/20</div>
</div>
```